# How to implement Firebase(FCM) Push Notifications on nuxtjs / vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Having devoted many hours to search the internet for a simple and straightforward way of how to implement Firebase FCM Push Notification on my nuxt project bore no fruit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to implement FCM Push Notifications on your NuxtJs/Vuejs project

Step 1

Create your nuxt app like `npx create-nuxt-app <your-app-name>`

Step 2

Install firebase `npm install firebase` and @nuxt/firebase `npm install @nuxt/firebase`

Step 3

Creating your firebase project

- Go to firebase console and create a project
  [image]
- Give it a name
  [image]
- Enable Google analytics if you like to then click on create

[image]

-Get some coffee as the projects creates ☕

- On this page you want to copy the config, which we will use later

[image]

- Finally, we land on the home page of our project on firebase, looks like below image

[image]

- Let's go back to our project

Step 4

On your `nuxt.config.js` add

```
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/firebase',    
  ],
  // firebase FCM starts here

  firebase: {
    lazy: false,
    config: {
      apiKey: <apiKey>,
      authDomain: <authDomain>,
      projected: <projectId>,
      storageBucket: <storageBucket>,
      messagingSenderId: <messagingSenderId>,
      appId: <appId>,
      measurementId: <measurementId>,
      databaseURL: <databaseURL>,
    },
    onFirebaseHosting: false,
    services: {
      messaging: true,
    }
  },


  messaging: {
    createServiceWorker: true,
    actions: [
      {
        action: 'goHome',
        url: 'https://localhost:3000'
      }
    ],
    fcmPublicVapidKey: <vapidKey> 
  },
```

To get your vapidKey navigate to **Project Settings** on your firebase console and select **Cloud Messaging**, scroll down and press on Generate Key Pair to have your vapidKey.See image below
[image]

copy and paste it on your `nuxt.config.js`

Step 5

On the `static` folder at your project root create a file named `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and paste the input the configs as below

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: <apiKey>,
      authDomain: <authDomain>,
      projected: <projectId>,
      storageBucket: <storageBucket>,
      messagingSenderId: <messagingSenderId>,
      appId: <appId>,
      measurementId: <measurementId>,
      databaseURL: <databaseURL>,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Step 6

On your index.vue configure it as follows

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Get Notified</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      listenersStarted: false,
      idToken: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.startListeners();
  },
  methods: {
    // FCM NOTIFICATION FUNCTIONS
    async startListeners() {
      await this.startOnMessageListener();
      await this.startTokenRefreshListener();
      await this.requestPermission();
      await this.getIdToken();
      this.listenersStarted = true;
    },
    startOnMessageListener() {
      try {
        this.$fire.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
          console.info("Message received : ", payload);
          console.log(payload.notification.body);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error : ", e);
      }
    },
    startTokenRefreshListener() {
      try {
        this.$fire.messaging.onTokenRefresh(async () => {
          try {
            await this.$fire.messaging.getToken();
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error : ", e);
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error : ", e);
      }
    },
    async requestPermission() {
      try {
        const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
        console.log("GIVEN notify perms");
        console.log(permission);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error : ", e);
      }
    },
    async getIdToken() {
      try {
        this.idToken = await this.$fire.messaging.getToken();
        console.log("TOKEN ID FOR this browser");
        console.log(this.idToken);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error : ", e);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Step 7

Run `npm run dev` , open your console to see if the permissions to display notifications are granted. Accept if promoted to allow notifications.

Step 8

Navigate to **Cloud Messaging** on firebase **Engage** menu and click on `Send your first message`. Type the content you would like your notification to have and select your app as the target user, there we have it you should see a notification on your browser like so

[image]